# How to inject spring context inside inner test class? Or what else workarounds exists?

Tags: java, spring, junit

I have a test class which should be structured with inner/nested classes inside it. A guy recommended me to use `@RunWith(HierarchicalContextRunner.class)` to run it. From what runners I've 
 already tried I like this more, and I'd like to keep using it. I've built my class based on this advice. It works nicely in outer class, all tests inside it work fine. But everything inside inner class throws this:

```
IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither GenericXmlContextLoader nor AnnotationConfigContextLoader was able to load an ApplicationContext from [MergedContextConfiguration@4aa22cc2 testClass = AbstractBaseEntityGenericDao_Test.Find_Method, locations = '{}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextCustomizers = set[[empty]], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]].
```

MyTestClass:

```
    @ActiveProfiles(profiles = "test") 
    @RunWith(HierarchicalContextRunner.class) 
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = {
            PersistenceConfig.class,
            RootConfig.class }) 
    @WebAppConfiguration 
    @Transactional 
    @Rollback 

    public class AbstractBaseEntityGenericDao_Test {

        private static final String[] CUSTOMER_NAMES = {"Veronica", "Hanna", "Eric"};

        @ClassRule
        public static final SpringClassRule SPRING_CLASS_RULE = new SpringClassRule();

        @Rule
        public final SpringMethodRule springMethodRule = new SpringMethodRule();

        @Autowired
        private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

        @Autowired
        private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        @Rule
        public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

        private AbstractClassStub abstractClassStub;

        private class AbstractClassStub extends AbstractBaseEntityGenericDao<NamedStubEntity> {

            public AbstractClassStub(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
                setClassInstance(NamedStubEntity.class);
                this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
            }

            @Override
            public void create(NamedStubEntity entity) {
                super.create(entity);
            }

            @Override
            public Optional find(Long id) {
                return super.find(id);
            }

            @Override
            public void update(NamedStubEntity entity) {
                super.update(entity);
            }

            @Override
            public void remove(@NonNull Long id) throws EntityNotFoundException {
                super.remove(id);
            }

            @Override
            public void remove(NamedStubEntity entity) {
                super.remove(entity);
            }
        }

        @Before
        public void setUp() throws Exception {
            abstractClassStub = new AbstractClassStub(sessionFactory);

            DbTestUtil.resetAutoIncrementColumns(applicationContext, "base_stub_entity");

            //...
        }

        @After
        public void tearDown() throws Exception {
            //...
        }

        @Test
        public void find_outer_test() {
            //Successful
        }


        public class Find_Method {

            @Test
            public void find_must_return_entity_in_database_by_id() {
                //Unsuccessful
            }

            @Test
            public void find_must_throw_NullPointerException() {
                //Unsuccessful
            }

            @Test
            public void find_should_return_BaseStubEntity() {
                //Unsuccessful
            }

        } }
```

Well... my question is - how to run everything with spring-context, not only the outer class?

**UPD:** 
Modified classes:

AbstractSpringTest

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
        PersistenceConfig.class,
        RootConfig.class
})
@WebAppConfiguration
@Transactional
@Rollback
public class AbstractSpringTest {

    @ClassRule
    public static final SpringClassRule SPRING_CLASS_RULE = new SpringClassRule();

    @Rule
    public final SpringMethodRule springMethodRule = new SpringMethodRule();

    @Autowired
    protected ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;
}
```

AbstractBaseEntityGenericDao_Test

```
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "test")
@RunWith(HierarchicalContextRunner.class)
public class AbstractBaseEntityGenericDao_Test extends AbstractSpringTest {

    private AbstractClassStub abstractClassStub;

    private class AbstractClassStub extends AbstractBaseEntityGenericDao<NamedStubEntity> {

        public AbstractClassStub(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
            setClassInstance(NamedStubEntity.class);
            this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        }

        @Override
        public void create(NamedStubEntity entity) {
            super.create(entity);
        }

        //...
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        abstractClassStub = new AbstractClassStub(sessionFactory);

        DbTestUtil.resetAutoIncrementColumns(applicationContext, "base_stub_entity");

        //...
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        //...
    }

    @Test
    public void find_must_find() {
        //Successful
    }

    public class Find_Method extends AbstractSpringTest {

        @Test
        public void find_must_throw_NullPointerException() {
            //Unsuccessful
        }

        @Test
        public void find_should_return_BaseStubEntity() {
            //Unsuccessful
        }

    }
}
```

How it looks in the debugger. And the debugger doesn't even go into the inner methods. It stops on class level [image]
I've tried to make the inner class as static to make it visible outside, but `HierarchicalContextRunner` stops seeing the test methods inside a nested class.

Answer (score 1):

You're very close. In fact, your approach may even be correct with the problem being related to configuration files rather than the test itself.

Broadly speaking, the simplest way is to put the related annotations also on the nested classes, which I assume is what you want to avoid.

A way to make it cleaner is to have your test classes all inherit from a common class. The class annotated will then be the common class. This works particularly well for me as I don't even have to write all the various Spring annotations in each and every test.
This will require you to use the `@ClassRule` and `@Rule` annotations in conjunction with `SpringClassRule` and `SpringMethodRule` and `@RunWith(Enclosed.class)` or similar... like you are already doing.

In your case, the `Find_Method` class would have to inherit from an `AbstractSpringTest` class which in turn would be annotated with your `@WebAppConfiguration` and associated annotations. Note however that the `Find_Method` class should be declared as `static`.

Here follows a partial extract of how such setup would look like:

```
package mypackage;

import org.junit.Rule;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.rules.SpringMethodRule;

import org.junit.ClassRule;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.rules.SpringClassRule;

import ...

@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { TestConfigurationClass1.class, TestConfigurationClass2.class })
public class AbstractSpringTest {

    @Rule
    public final SpringMethodRule springMethodRule = new SpringMethodRule();

    @ClassRule
    public static final SpringClassRule SPRING_CLASS_RULE = new SpringClassRule();
}
```

And here's how your test classes would look like:

```
@RunWith(Enclosed.class)
public class MyTestClass extends AbstractSpringTest {

  ...
  public static class MyNestedTestClass extends AbstractSpringTest {
    ...
  }

  public static class MyOtherNestedTestClass extends AbstractSpringTest {
    ...
  }
}
```

Needless to say, using "rules" allows you to have whatever `@RunWith` annotation you see fit for your purpose. In my case I find very useful the possibility to use this approach to run `@Parameterized` tests.

The error you described, however, seems to point to problems in loading the associated configuration files (`application.properties`, `application-context.xml` and similar). The general advice is to double-check that all the configuration files are available on the right path of the `classpath` for use by the tests. Note that this means for example checking the contents of the `target` directory as well as excluding that the IDE is having a "temper tantrum" and refusing manage specific resources appropriately, the best way being to run a `mvn clean install`.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. 
It throws inside the inner class, "NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' " everything inside outer class seems workings. I've taken away @Autowired fields to the abstract class, but I still get the same Exception. In debugger all fields (SessionFactory, ApplicationContext, SpringMethodRule) are null.

Comment: In debugger springMethodRule inside inner class shows this:  
((AbstractBaseEntityGenericDao_Test)this).springMethodRule = Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'com.beginnercourse.softcomputer.abstractions.persistence.dao.AbstractBaseEntityGenericDao_Test.Find_Method' to 'com.beginnercourse.softcomputer.abstractions.persistence.dao.AbstractBaseEntityGenericDao_Test'

Comment: Please provide the modified code, so I can have a look.

Comment: Added UPD section to post.

Comment: I can see two differences compared to my code. Not sure it's them, but it's worth trying even if only to eliminate them as the cause of the problem. Try replacing the ```HierarchicalContextRunner``` with ```Enclosed``` and make the two nested test classes ```static```. If it works, try re-introducing them one by one. If they don't work, comment here again and we'll continue.

Comment: It throws the same IllegalStateException(on top of the question) from inner methods, the outer one doesn't even run, but I guess it is Enclosed.class specific.

Comment: Does your application rely to any configuration file? (application.properties, application-context.xml and the likes)

Comment: You're right about Enclosed.class runner. In such aproach, we have to use runners which works with static classes. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12294761/spring-injection-into-inner-class

Comment: Yes, it does. I have 3 .properties files which loaded by config classes. And AbstractSpringTest include them through @ContextConfiguration

Comment: My current guess is that it's failing to load one or more of these files. Verify their paths in respect to JUnit to make sure they are in the expected location. I found occasionally that a ```mvn clean install``` is necessary as the IDE doesn't always copy those files even though it should. In general, make sure the configuration files are in the locations expected by the tests when they run.

Comment: It's something related with PersistenceConfig from where load .properties files. Without it, the whole algorithm works. And I have a hint that's IDE unexpected behavior - I've changed the test name, made "Invalidate Chane & Restart", deleted "target" directory run "mvn clean install", but in debugger, I see the old name. I don't know where does it come from.
Thank you for help, I've learned a lot. Perhaps I should formulate a new question to structure information.

Comment: Makes sense. On my side, I'll update my answer to reflect that the actual issue appears to be related to the configuration, as well as the other findings. At least, it will give a clue to other readers who might have a similar issue.